# Show error message if that particular content is not in database

Tags: php, mysql

Here I have code where user is going to be created, they have to enter one accesscode given by admin. That accesscode is limited by some users like `10` or `20`. After that it shows error like `your accesscode is limited`. So until now, it's working fine.

Now if user tries to enter accesscode that is not given by admin it has to show error message like `your accesscode is wrong`.

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
require('../config.php'); 
require_once($CFG->dirroot . '/user/editlib.php'); 
$errorMessage = ''; 
$successMessage = ''; 
if(isset($_SESSION['successMessage'])) { 
    $successMessage = $_SESSION['successMessage']; 
    unset($_SESSION['successMessage']); 
} 

if (isset($_POST['register'])) { 
    $errors = array(); 
    $data = array(); 
    $chk_sql = "SELECT * FROM {user} u where username = ?"; 
    if (!empty($chk_sql) ) {
        $errorMessage = 'Username already taken';
    }
    if(!$chk_username = $DB->get_record_sql($chk_sql, array($_POST['username']))) { 
        $secret = $_POST['secret']; 
        $access_code_sql = "SELECT * FROM {accesscode} WHERE random_no= ? and `number` > `used` and status=1"; 
        if($chk_secret = $DB->get_record_sql($access_code_sql, array($secret))) { 
            $cadminid = $chk_secret->cadmin_id; 
            $clientid = $chk_secret->clientid; 
            $DB->execute("UPDATE {accesscode} SET used = used+1 WHERE random_no = '$secret'"); 

            $insert_record = new stdClass(); 
            $insert_record->firstname = $_POST['firstname']; 
            $insert_record->lastname = $_POST['lastname']; 
            $insert_record->username = $_POST['username']; 
            $insert_record->secret = $secret; 
            $insert_record->password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT); 
            $insert_record->timecreated = time(); 
            $insert_record->maildigest = $cadminid; 
            $insert_record->maildisplay = $clientid; 
            $insert_record->idnumber = 1; 
            $insert_record->mnethostid = 1; 
            $insert_record->confirmed = 1; 
            $insert_record->email = $_POST['email']; 
            if ($result = $DB->insert_record('user', $insert_record)) { 
                $_SESSION['successMessage'] = "record created successfully"; 
                header('Location: register.php'); 
            } else 
                $errorMessage = "error! can you please try again"; 
        } else 
            $errorMessage = "your access code limit completed";
    } 
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you give us more information about your problem? What doesn't work?Try some "var_dump()" in your loop to know if you pass through or not so you can tell us where is the problem !

But first thing I see is here :

```
if(! $chk_username = $DB->get_record_sql($chk_sql, array($_POST['username'])) )
```

and here :

```
if($result = $DB->insert_record('user', $insert_record))
```

You should use "==" or "===" because using "=" means you assign a value to "$chk_username" and "result".

Then here is some librairie you can use if you want to display flash message, this is just for your information :
https://github.com/plasticbrain/PhpFlashMessages

And if you want to do it in JS you can use : https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr

Hope it helps !

Comment: no actually..i showed this message for  $errorMessage = "your access code limit completed"; one condition..if it is not that condition i need to show another error message

Comment: I understand, but the problem is that you can't display the error message, right? Try to use "==" instead of "=" because if you use a "if" statement with "=" it will be true 100% of the time because you assign the value, you don't compare them

Comment: ok..if i use == how i can write another else for that condition..can you please epxlain me..

Comment: Can you edit your question and just explain the structure you want to build? For example : test 1 (var 1 == statement) -> if true : test 2 else -> error msg; test 2 (var 2 == statement) -> if true : test 3 else -> error msg; etc. Hard to exlain in comment so edit your question and I will try to help you in my anwser

Comment: Good ! So what was the problem?

Answer (score 0):

i changed the condition like this

```
 <?php 
require('../config.php'); 
require_once($CFG->dirroot . '/user/editlib.php');

$errorMessage = ''; 
$successMessage = ''; 
if(isset($_SESSION['successMessage'])) 
{ 
$successMessage = $_SESSION['successMessage']; 
unset($_SESSION['successMessage']); 
} 

if (isset($_POST['register'])) { 
$errors = array(); 
$data = array(); 
$chk_sql = "SELECT * FROM {user} u where username = ?"; 
if (!empty($chk_sql) ) {
    $errorMessage='Username already taken';
    }
if(!$chk_username = $DB->get_record_sql($chk_sql, array($_POST['username'])) 
) 
{ 
$secret = $_POST['secret']; 
$access_code_sql = "SELECT * FROM {accesscode} WHERE random_no= ?  and 
status=1"; 
if($chk_secret = $DB->get_record_sql($access_code_sql, array($secret)) ) 
{ 

if ( $chk_secret->used >= $chk_secret->number ) { 
$errorMessage = "your access code limit completed..";
}else
{
$cadminid = $chk_secret->cadmin_id; 
$clientid = $chk_secret->clientid; 
$DB->execute("UPDATE {accesscode} SET used = used+1 WHERE random_no = '$secret'"); 

$insert_record = new stdClass(); 
$insert_record->firstname = $_POST['firstname']; 
$insert_record->lastname = $_POST['lastname']; 
$insert_record->username = $_POST['username']; 
$insert_record->secret = $secret; 
$insert_record->password = password_hash($_POST['password'], 
PASSWORD_DEFAULT); 
$insert_record->timecreated = time(); 
$insert_record->maildigest = $cadminid; 
$insert_record->maildisplay = $clientid; 
$insert_record->idnumber = 1; 
$insert_record->mnethostid = 1; 
$insert_record->confirmed = 1; 
$insert_record->email = $_POST['email']; 
if($result = $DB->insert_record('user', $insert_record)) 
{ 
$_SESSION['successMessage'] = "record created successfully"; 
header('Location: register.php'); 
} 
else 
$errorMessage = "error! can you please try again"; 
}
 }
else
$errorMessage = "your access code is wrong..";
}

} 
?>
```

it's working..